# Creating a dictionary

Tags: beginner, ruby, hash-map, rspec

I have a Ruby programming task. My code passes all the rspec requirements, but I am not sure if I've done it in the right way. And I'm not quite sure why I need `:entries` there...

Here is the rspec test:

```
# # Topics
#
# * Hash
# * Array
# * instance variables
# * regular expressions

require '11_dictionary'

describe Dictionary do
  before do
    @d = Dictionary.new
  end

  it "is empty when created" do
    expect(@d.entries).to eq({})
  end

  it "can add whole entries with keyword and definition" do
    @d.add("fish" => "aquatic animal")
    expect(@d.entries).to eq({"fish" => "aquatic animal"})
    expect(@d.keywords).to eq(["fish"])
  end

  it "add keywords (without definition)" do
    @d.add("fish")
    expect(@d.entries).to eq({"fish" => nil})
    expect(@d.keywords).to eq(["fish"])
  end

  it "can check whether a given keyword exists" do
    expect(@d.include?("fish")).to be_falsey
  end

  it "doesn't cheat when checking whether a given keyword exists" do
    expect(@d.include?("fish")).to be_falsey # if the method is empty, this test passes with nil returned
    @d.add("fish")
    expect(@d.include?("fish")).to be_truthy # confirms that it actually checks
    expect(@d.include?("bird")).to be_falsey # confirms not always returning true after add
  end

  it "doesn't include a prefix that wasn't added as a word in and of itself" do
    @d.add("fish")
    expect(@d.include?("fi")).to be_falsey
  end

  it "doesn't find a word in empty dictionary" do
    expect(@d.find("fi")).to be_empty # {}
  end

  it "finds nothing if the prefix matches nothing" do
    @d.add("fiend")
    @d.add("great")
    expect(@d.find("nothing")).to be_empty
  end

  it "finds an entry" do
    @d.add("fish" => "aquatic animal")
    expect(@d.find("fish")).to eq({"fish" => "aquatic animal"})
  end

  it "finds multiple matches from a prefix and returns the entire entry (keyword + definition)" do
    @d.add("fish" => "aquatic animal")
    @d.add("fiend" => "wicked person")
    @d.add("great" => "remarkable")
    expect(@d.find("fi")).to eq({"fish" => "aquatic animal", "fiend" => "wicked person"})
  end

  it "lists keywords alphabetically" do
    @d.add("zebra" => "African land animal with stripes")
    @d.add("fish" => "aquatic animal")
    @d.add("apple" => "fruit")
    expect(@d.keywords).to eq(%w(apple fish zebra))
  end

  it "can produce printable output like so: [keyword] 'definition'" do
    @d.add("zebra" => "African land animal with stripes")
    @d.add("fish" => "aquatic animal")
    @d.add("apple" => "fruit")
    expect(@d.printable).to eq(%Q{[apple] "fruit"\n[fish] "aquatic animal"\n[zebra] "African land animal with stripes"})
  end
end
```

Here is my code:

```
class Dictionary
    attr_accessor :entries

    def initialize
        @hash={}
    end

    def add(a)
        if a.class == Hash
            a.each_pair { |k, v|
                @hash[k]=v
            }
        else
           @hash[a]=nil 
       end
    end
    def entries
        @hash
    end

    def keywords
        @hash.keys.sort
    end
    def include?(k)
        @hash.key?(k)
    end

    def printable
        str=[]
        key=@hash.keys.sort
        key.each do |el|
            @hash.each_pair do |k,v|
                if k==el
                    str << "[#{k}] \"#{v}\""
                end
            end
        end
        return str.join("\n")
    end

    def find(str)
        if str.class == Hash
            str.each_pair { |k, v|
               return (@hash.select { |k,v| k.include?(k)})
            }
        elsif str.class == String 
            return (@hash.select {|k,v| k.include?(str)})
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: For future reference, you might want to look at [recommendations for posting a good quality question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562). I would have liked to see a bit of a summary of what your code does and the functionality it provides.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Dictionary
    attr_accessor :entries
```

Indentation in Ruby is two spaces, not four. You have that correct in your specs, but not in the application code.

Also, you create here a pair of methods, `entries=` which you never use anywhere, and `entries`, which you overwrite further down, anyway. Either get rid of this line, or (preferred!) actually make use of those methods.

```
    def initialize
        @hash={}
```

There should be a space on both sides of the `=` sign. This applies to operators in general.

[Note: there are *some* style guides that advocate not using spaces around the `=` sign for optional parameters with default arguments, but a) this is not universally accepted and b) not the case here anyway.]

```
    end

    def add(a)
```

This should probably be called `<<` instead.

[Note: I realize, this is prescribed by the spec. IMO, the spec should be changed.]

```
        if a.class == Hash
```

You should *never* compare the class of an object like this. Ideally, you should use runtime ad-hoc polymorphism. If that isn't possible, *at least* use `Object#is_a?`, `Object#kind_of?`, or `Module#===`.

```
            a.each_pair { |k, v|
                @hash[k]=v
            }
```

There are two different camps when it comes to block styles: one camp says to use `{`/`}` for one-liners and `do`/`end` for multiple lines. The other camp says to use `{`/`}` for "functional" blocks and `do`/`end` for side-effecting blocks.

Regardless of which camp you follow: your block has three lines *and* side-effects, so it should use the keyword form.

```
        else
           @hash[a]=nil 
       end
    end
```

There should be an empty between the two method definitions.

```
    def entries
        @hash
    end

    def keywords
        @hash.keys.sort
    end
    def include?(k)
        @hash.key?(k)
    end

    def printable
```

This should be called `to_s`. `to_s` is the standard name for a method that converts an object into a textual representation. It is used automatically by methods such as `Array#join` or `Kernel#puts`.

[Note: I realize, this is prescribed by the spec. IMO, the spec should be changed.]

```
        str=[]
        key=@hash.keys.sort
        key.each do |el|
            @hash.each_pair do |k,v|
                if k==el
                    str << "[#{k}] \"#{v}\""
```

You could save yourself some hassle here by using something else than `"` to delimit the string.

This pattern, where you initialize an accumulator to an "empty" value and then iterate over a collection while appending to the accumulator at every iteration, is called a *Catamorphism*, `fold`, or `reduce`. In Ruby, it is known as `inject`.

However, in this case, it can also be done even simpler, with a `map`.

```
                end
            end
        end
        return str.join("\n")
```

The `return` is superfluous here, the return value of a method is the value of the last expression which is evaluated inside the method body.

```
    end

    def find(str)
        if str.class == Hash
            str.each_pair { |k, v|
               return (@hash.select { |k,v| k.include?(k)})
            }
```

There is nothing in the spec about passing `Hash`es to find. In fact, you named your parameter `str` clearly indicating that you expect it to be a `String`. Then why even bother checking for `Hash`es?

```
        elsif str.class == String 
            return (@hash.select {|k,v| k.include?(str)})
```

Here you check whether the key *includes* the search string. However, from the *documentation* in the spec, it appears that the search string should be a *prefix* of the key. Unfortunately, there is actually no test in the spec to test for that distinction.

```
        end
    end
end
```

This is what it would look like with those suggestions applied:

```
class Dictionary
  attr_reader :entries

  def initialize
    self.entries = {}
  end

  def add(a)
    case a
    when Hash then entries.merge!(a)
    else           entries[a] = nil
    end
  end

  def keywords
    entries.keys.sort
  end

  def include?(k)
    entries.key?(k)
  end

  def printable
    entries.
      sort.
      map {|k, v| ["[#{k}]", unless v.nil? then %Q["#{v}"] end] }.
      map(&:compact).
      map {|kvp| kvp.join(' ') }.
      join("\n")
  end

  def find(key)
    entries.select {|k, v| k.start_with?(key) }
  end

  private

  attr_writer :entries
end
```

Comment: I find `unless v.nil? then %Q["#{v}"] end` a bit hard to understand, do you think a ternary could be better?

Comment: I don't like the conditional operator very much. I strongly prefer a conditional expression. I went back and forth between the positive and the negative formulation, though: `unless v.nil? then %Q["#{v}"] end` vs. `if v.nil? then nil else %Q["#{v}"] end`. In the end, I decided *against* the positive formulation, because even though the condition is easier to read, the "interesting" stuff happens in the `else` branch. In the negative formulation, the interesting stuff happens in the `then` branch, and, even better, the non-interesting stuff allows us to leave out the `else` altogether.

Comment: All in all, I don't believe `v.nil? ? nil : %Q["#{v}"]` will buy much over `if v.nil? then nil else %Q["#{v}"] end`. See also this comment of mine on another answer for some of my thoughts on the conditional operator: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116236/hackerrank-challenge-dictionaries-and-maps/116255#comment218516_116255

Comment: Honestly, I find the whole idea of a dictionary with incomplete entries just weird, and the weirdness in the `to_s` is actually just a symptom of that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag  Thank you very much for your feedback. I will take into consideration some of your suggestions. My main question, however, remains open. Does my code do the stuff that I am suppose to learn according to the spec?